# Adding multiple objects with properties to a list

Tags: c#, list

I have been tasked with making a shopping basket program in C#
I have a quantity property but I can't seem to add more than a quantity of one to my list.

```
public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestPrice, int quantity)
    {
        foreach (OrderItem product in basket)
        {
            if (product.ProductName == productName)
            {
                product.AddItems(latestPrice, quantity);
                return;
            }
        }
        OrderItem nProduct = new OrderItem(productName, latestPrice, quantity);
        nProduct.AddItems(latestPrice, quantity);
        basket.Add(nProduct);
    }

    public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestPrice)
    {
        AddProduct(productName, latestPrice, 1);
    }
```

Comment: why?  any error? be more specific in what you are asking

Comment: any specific reason to `return` in the `if` statement. were you looking for `break` instead?

Comment: be more specific about problem?

Comment: What does `nProduct.AddItems(latestPrice, quantity)` do? You are probably calling `AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestPrice)` which defaults quantity to 1

Comment: The problem is I need to be able to display a total quantity of items in the basket. e.g.: (bread, quantity 2), (milk, quantity 3) - I want it to display that the basket has a quantity of 5. But instead it is coming as 2. (Using unit testing to determine)

Comment: nProduct is for if the item is not already in the basket, it creates it. And the second AddProduct is for if the user does not specify a quantity, quantity of that item is default to 1. (I was told to make that in my spec.)

Comment: @user3177354 "I want it to display that the basket has a quantity of 5" - `decimal quantity = 0m; foreach (OrderItem product in basket) { quantity = quantity + product.Quantity; }`, assuming that `OrderItem` has a property `Quantity`. - If you're using LINQ you can write that as: `decimal quantity = basket.Sum(p => p.Quantity);`

Comment: Can you please post code of your `OrderItem`, mainly `AddItems(string, int)` but also constructor and related? It looks to me the problem is there.

Comment: `public void AddItems(decimal newLatestPrice, int quantityToAdd)
        {

            if (newLatestPrice <= 0 || quantityToAdd <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("You may not have a negative value for price or quantity.");
            }

            if (newLatestPrice > 0 && quantityToAdd > 0)
            {
                quantity += quantityToAdd;
                latestPrice = newLatestPrice;
            }
        }`

Comment: I look at this code and it looks like I'm looking at a cryptic puzzle...and the more I read the explanations in these comments the more cryptic it becomes. Whoever gave you this task didn't bother reading your resume!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
List<Product> basket = new List<Product>();

public void AddOrUpdateProducts(Product p, int quantity)
{
    // Update
    foreach (Product product in basket)
    {
        if (product.Id == p.Id)
        {
            product.Quantity += quantity;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Add
    basket.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(p, quantity));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you do not have quantity at all. If you need to add 5 breads, then add 5 times one bread.

When showing basket content, combine similar products, so that the customer will see

```
bread    x5
butter   x1
```

Comment: I can't. I need to have it due to the spec I have to follow.